# A set of nonlinear coupled ODE

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have reached a set of ODE as 
\begin{align}
&\ddot{\vec{a}}(t)+\omega_0^2\frac{\cos{(b(t))}\sin{(a(t))}}{a(t)}\vec{a}(t)=0\\
&\ddot{b}(t)+\omega_0^2\cos{(a(t))}\sin{(b(t))}=0
\end{align}
that describes the dynamics of a quantum operator $\hat{\Phi}(t)$ in the Heisenberg picture such that
\begin{align}
\hat{\Phi}(t)=\vec{a}(t).\vec{\sigma}+b(t)\mathbb{1}
\end{align}
In the equations above $a(t)$ represents the norm of $\vec{a}(t)=(a_x(t),a_y(t),a_z(t))$ and $\omega_0$ is the oscillation frequency. I need to solve this with the initial condition given as
\begin{align}
&a_x(0)=A \quad a_y(0)=0 \quad a_z(0)=0 \quad b(0)=0 \\ 
&\dot{a}_x(0)=0 \quad \dot{a}_y(0)=B \quad \dot{a}_z(0)=0 \quad \dot{b}(0)=0 
\end{align}
for nonzer $A$ and $B$. As far as I know there is no analytical solution for such an ODE recalling that even a 1D version of this $\ddot{a}(t)+\omega_0^2 \sin{(a(t))}=0$ can not be solved exactly. I wonder if this set of coupled nonlinear ODE has been studied in any context and if anyone has any intuition about its behavior.

Comment: While $\ddot a(t)+\omega_0^2\sin(a(t))=0$ does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions, look at the Jacobi Amplitude Function $\phi(t,k)$ for a solution. It has the special property that $$\frac{d^2\phi(t,k)}{dt^2}=-\frac{k^2}{2}\sin(\phi(t,k)).$$ I know this does not answer your question, but it might help.